# Difference between at() and row().col()

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

Given `opencv::Mat m1,m2`, I want to check if `m1[i][j]` and `m2[i][j]` are equal.

I've seen that there are two ways to do this:

```
if(m1.row(i).col(j) == m2.row(i).col(j))
```

and:

```
if(m1.at<float>(i,j)==m2.at<float>(i,j))
```

Notice that both `m1` and `m2` are SIFT matrix descriptors (so `float` is the element type).

My question is: what's the difference between the two access methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the net result of the two operations is the same, the first one is more costly:

- `m1.row(i)` creates a `Mat` object representing row `i`, then
- `col(j)` is called on the `Mat` returned from `m1.row(i)` to get a single-element `Mat` representing object at `(i, j)`
- The same sequence of operations is applied to `m2`
- The two `Mat` objects are compared with `==`
- Four temporary objects get deallocated

In contrast, `m1.at<float>(i,j)` simply returns a `float`, which then gets compared to the other float, without creating any additional objects.

Comment: But the first solution has the advantage that we don't need to know the `Mat` type at compile time. Is that correct?

Comment: @justHelloWorld That's correct, the object type being compared is `Mat`, so you do not need to state it explicitly at compile time.